# What is latent parsing in NLP?

Tags: parsing, natural-language-processing

I'm reading a paper describing a NLP work, and I hardly catch the concept of a term, "latent parsing".

Original paper: http://web.stanford.edu/~angeli/papers/2013-acl-temporal.pdf

The figure in the page 6 seems to be helpful (I can't upload the figure because of my reputation)

Comment: Thank you for your comments and please excuse me. I deleted my question in the stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to explain what I understand after quickly looking at the paper. "Latent" is used to describe techniques that uncover the hidden meaning of a piece of text (see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_indexing). In this paper the authors are using machine learning to do latent semantic parsing of temporal expressions.
Essentially one wants to compute a unique represesentation of a temporal expression, for example "March 14" could mean "March 14th" but also "March 2PM". By using regular expressions one can't tell what "March 14" means but by using estimation one knows that March 14th would be the most likely interpretation of that expression and so get the (most likely) correct parsing.

Comment: Thank you very much:) I hadn't been sure about the meaning of latent but your answer make it clear. Moreover the example is very helpful to understand the difference among the research and previous works